# How do I add a Parameter for Multiple Customer Numbers?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have a cube with Account Numbers stored as text strings.  I need to create a report with a parameter that users can enter a list of Account Numbers.

I've created my query and in the filter I have "Account Number".  The Operator is "equals" and I have ticked the Parameter check box.

If I run the report now, I can select multiple Account Numbers, but we have over 40,000 accounts so it can take a while to find and tick all the ones I want to report on.  I want to be able to type or paste a list of Accounts.

If I go in to the Parameter Properties and set Available Values to "none" I can enter my list of accounts, but when I try to view the report I get this error.

*The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.*

I'm guessing I have to go in to the Dataset Properties and do something to the Account Number parameter to format the list of accounts in the correct way, but I have no idea how to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this.

Create your query with Account Number as a parameter.

In the @CustomerAccountNumber parameter, make sure its type is Text and tick Allow multiple values.  Set Available Values to None and set Default Values to No default value.

Go to the properties of your dataset and go to Parameters.  In the CustomerAccountNumber parameter set the Parameter Value to this:

```
=Split(“[Customer].[Account Number].&["+Replace(Join(Parameters!CustomerAccountNumber.Value,"],”)+”]”,”,”,”,[Customer].[Account Number].&["),",")
```

Now run your report and you should be able to type in a list of account numbers and get results for just those accounts.

I found my answer [here](http://erikasblog.datainspirations.com/2010/01/21/passing-multi-value-sql-parameters-to-an-mdx-query-in-reporting-services/).